# MiniTest ruby class queries return nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autotest, minitest

I am running Rails 3.2.8 and using MinitTest spec for my testing. I have autotest manage my testing suite and everything works great except for one thing. I have a Contacts table that is managed by ActiveRecord with MySQL and a CsvImport custom ruby class that does not have a database table. When I run the application in IRB everything works as expected but when the test is ran through the test suite all the Contact.find / Contact.where / Contact.map query type calls that are in the Ruby class are returned nil.

Here is an example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CsvRowManagerTest < MiniTest::Spec
  describe 'import tests' do
    let(:row) { Hash['name' => 'test'] }
    let(:rm) { CsvRowManager.new(row) }
    it "should return an array of stuff" do
      rm.contacts.wont_be_nil
    end
  end
end

class CsvRowManager
  attr_accessor :row, :contacts

  def initialize(row)
    @row = row
    @contacts = Contact.all.map(&:name) #<-- returns nil
  end

end
```

More of a demonstration than anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got the test environment setup in the database config file? It sounds like you've got development setup fine

Comment: Yes. It looks like this

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3

Comment: Do you have a sample test? Have you setup your fixtures?

Comment: Are you using minitest-rails or have you rolled your own minitest support in rails?

Comment: I updated the example to be a bit more clear. No fixtures, using factories but possibly my testing philosophy needs some debugging. Blowmage, your minitest-rails gem is impressive but I am just using the the standard minitest library for now. This example should work though right?

Comment: @yeaslayer There are many reasons your models could not be loading. Can you post your `test_helper.rb` file?

Comment: Posted. I still have some test unit tests pardon the clutter.

Comment: @yeaslayer Shoot me an email so I can set up a remote pair to help you debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the test database wasn't cloning the data from development! Doh. Thanks for all the help you two; you pushed me in the right direction. @Blowmage even offered to remote debug my problem with me. What a kick ass dude!